# Possible Dimensions of Linear Codes with length $n$ over $GF(q)$

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, coding-theory

We need to calculate the number of linear codes(note not codewords) with length $n$ over $GF(q)$
,
the number of linear codes with dimension k is
$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(q^{n} - q^i)}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(q^{k} - q^i)}$$,let's assume $n=20, q=5$ but in our case dimension is not specified so we need to sum over all the possible dimension , for linear codes the possible dimension are $d=[1,n]$ (correct me if I am wrong) where $n = 20$  in our case , so the formula will be
$$\sum_{k=1}^{20}\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(5^{20} - 5^i)}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(5^{k} - 5^i)}$$
which gives about $1.456*10^{70}$, I could not find any resources about the possible dimensions of linear codes, could you please give some resources specifically investigating it for linear codes, and hamming codes.

Comment: aside from that my assumptions are correct?, the case for k=0 does not make sense in the formula

Comment: Apologies, I have deleted my previous comment. Your formula should be the empty product when $k=0$ giving $1$, the number of $0$-dimensional subspaces.  But no matter; what you are doing is adding up the Gaussian binomial coefficients [except leading term if you exclude $k=0$) and that seems not to have a nice closed form. But two of the answers to the following question give  references to the sort of combinatorics that's involved: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89934/sum-of-gaussian-binomial-coefficients